# Facebook Graph API: feed method results are missing type: status from: me

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph API to fetch status that I posted to my own wall.

I have tried using the graph API statuses method and I am able to get my most recent 100 status updates:

a query like this: /me/statuses?since=2010-09-01&until=2010-10-01 returns many results for my account.

similarly, I would expect this query: /me/feed?since=2010-09-01&until=2010-10-01 to return those same posts from me to my wall (i.e. type: status, from: me) as the above query, along with posts to my wall from others, etc..

what actually happens, however is that the /me/feed query above returns all posts EXCEPT those from ME

Can anyone explain this behavior?

*it seems to be related to the time, for example if i only go back 2 months (eg: /me/feed?since=2011-12-01&until=2012-01-01), everything works fine